# Error exporting Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, acquia

I am up with `drupal` development in a `localhost` environment. I am using `Acquia Drupal Stack`. Now I want to export it to my domain. When I try to export it as an archive from `Export` functionality in the `Acquia Drupal Stack`, I get an error :

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Always remember, never use such stupid application. Always do it manually!

Answer (score 1):

Moving it manually is quite easy. This is how I'd do it when i only have simple FTP/phpMyAdmin access:

1. Deactivate bandwidth optimization and caching (in Menu Configuration/Development/Performance), run Cron ('Configuration/System/Cron'), run Update ('/update.php'), clear all caches (Switching the site to maintenance mode might be a good idea as well).
2. Export your database (via Terminal/`mysqldump`, phpMyAdmin or the [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) Module), preferably in zip format.
3. Import the database to your new server.
4. FTP all files to your server (Set default permissions to `550` for folders, `440` for files). Only sites/default/files and its contents need write permission (`775`)
5. Adjust `settings.php` (Base URL, DB Login) and maybe `.htaccess` (eg. RewriteBase) for your new server.

If you get a white screen instead of your homepage, try the user login page (`/user/login`). Logging in and clearing caches again fixes this for me most of the time.